# Correctly setting user permissions via SSH

Tags: sftp, users, user-permissions

I'm getting stuck with user permissions on a LAMP stack (using Digital Ocean if it matters). Here's my setup.

User `dev` has the following groups: 
`dev www-data`

The `/var/www` folder has been set so that the owner is `www-data:www-data`, it looks like this:

```
 drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Mar 30 17:41 www
```

If I use the `dev` user to sftp in, everything looks good, but if I then upload a file, the new file has the ownership of `dev:dev`.

This becomes a problem when I have a new user called `dev2` that is also working in the same directory as they can't delete or overwrite the files that belong to `dev`.

My experience with users is unfortunately limited to using cPanel, where I can create multiple FTP users that don't have this access/overlap issue. How can I do this via terminal?

Answer (score 0):

The `g+s` bit on directories will impose the group-of-the-parent-directory (BSD style) instead of the default group-of-the-process (SysV style). So, something like

```
chmod g+s /var/www
```

(and also on any subdirectories) should cause the `www-data` group to be preserved on the creation of new files thereunder. Another option may be to use the so-called POSIX acls (see `setfacl(1)`) which while more complicated can allow multiple groups to access the files. (You may end up with some cron jobs to audit/set the permissions, regardless, or configuration management can also enforce permissions on a directory tree, depending on how much trouble you want to go to.)